# Unable to generate correct hash table for columns in CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a CSV file with the following columns,

```
ZoneMaterialName1,ZoneThickness1
Copper,2.5
Copper,2.5
Aluminium,3
Zinc, 
Zinc,
Zinc,6
Aluminium,4
```

As can be seen, some values are repeating multiple times, and can occasionally be blank or a period.

I would like a hash table with unique values only, like

```
ZoneMaterialName1,ZoneThickness1
Copper:[2.5]
Aluminium:[3,4]
Zinc:[6]
```

Here is the code I came up with, the output is missing the float numbers like 2.5 and allowing whitespaces and periods as well.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
afile = open('/mnt/c/python_test/Book2.csv', 'r+')
csvReader1 = csv.reader(afile)

reader = csv.DictReader(open('/mnt/c/python_test/Book2.csv'))
nodes = defaultdict(type(''))

for row in reader:

       if (row['ZoneThickness1'] !=' ' and row['ZoneThickness1'] !='.'):
               nodes[row['ZoneMaterialName1']]+=(row['ZoneThickness1'])
new_dict = {a:list(set(b)) for a, b in nodes.items()}
print new_dict
```

**Approach:** I create a dictionary originally and converted its values to a set.

Comment: do you ever use csvReader1? why is it included here?

Comment: also you can't be running both python3.x _and_ 2.7, which is it?

Comment: Yes, That line shouldn't be there. Also its 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you try to cast the second column to `float` and add only those values that are valid floating point numbers.
Also, you can use a `set` to avoid duplicate values for the some material.

This could be done like this (I used `Python 3.x` since you tagged this question for both python versions):

```
import collections
import csv

result = collections.defaultdict(set)

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    csv_r = csv.DictReader(f)

    for row in csv_r:
        try:
            v = float(row['ZoneThickness1'])
        except ValueError:
            # skip this line, because it is not a valid float
            continue

        # this will add the material if it doesn't exist yet and
        # will also add the value if it doesn't exist yet for this material
        result[row['ZoneMaterialName1']].add(v)

for k, v in result.items():
    print(k, v)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Copper {2.5}
Aluminium {3.0, 4.0}
Zinc {6.0}
```